# What is the dimension of $f[x]$ over $f$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $f[x]$ be the ring of polynomials in one variable $x$ over the field $f$ with the relation $x^n =0$, for some fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

How can I find the dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wish to compute the dimension of the vector space $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$ over a field $k$. To do so, note that $\beta=\{[1],[x],\dotsc,[x^{n-1}]\}$ is a basis for $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$. Indeed, suppose
$$
\lambda_0[1]+\lambda_1[x]+\dotsb+\lambda_{n-1}[x^{n-1}]=0\tag{1}
$$
in $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$. Note that (1) holds if and only if
$$
\lambda_0+\lambda_1x+\dotsb+\lambda_{n-1}x^{n-1}=f(x)x^n\tag{2}
$$
in $k[x]$ where $p(x)\in k[x]$. But the degrees of (2) have to match. That is (2) holds if and only if
$$
\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\dotsb=\lambda_{n-1}=0
$$
and $f(x)=0$. Thus $\beta$ is linearly independent in $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$. Clearly $\beta$ spans $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$. Hence $\beta$ is a basis of $k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle$ so that
$$
\dim k[x]/\langle x^n\rangle=n
$$